# how to handle the method type in ListItem of type button in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, navigation, material-ui, react-admin

In raect-admin I have thomething like this:

```
   <ListItem 
      button
      to={`/XXX/${record.id}`}
      component={Link}
      key={record.id}
   >
```

when clicking on the link I want to render the show component but get the edit component.

Do you knoe why? and how to fix it?

and actually how to handle the method type? GET PUT DELETE POST?

thank you!

Comment: We need more context like your app.js and routing. I think the problem is in your routing stack.

Comment: thank you, i understated that something wrong in my routing. 
I checked but stiil didint find what's wrong, for now I did like @François Zaninotto answer and this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try routing to the `/[resource]/[id]/name` route:

```
   <ListItem 
      button
      to={`/XXX/${record.id}/show`}
      component={Link}
      key={record.id}
   >
```

As for the GET / DELETE / POST verb, this is something you should handle in your dataProvider (see https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html for details).